# How to integrate a dropdown menu and search input box in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, drop-down-menu

I am trying to build a native search of a drop down menu. This [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wLzs4/3/) has a separate input box searching through a drop down (code below as well).

```
<form>
search <input type="text" id="realtxt" onkeyup="javascript:searchSel();"/>
  <select id="realitems">
    <option value="">select...</option>
    <option value="1">Power hungry</option>
    <option value="2">Super man</option>
    <option value="3">Hyperactive</option>
    <option value="4">Bored</option>
    <option value="5">Human</option>
  </select>
</form>

function searchSel() {
  var input = document.getElementById('realtxt').value.toLowerCase(); 
  var output = document.getElementById('realitems').options;

  for(var i=0; i<output.length; i++)
      if (output[i].text.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) != -1 ){
          output[i].selected = true;
          break;
      }
  if (input == ''){
    output[0].selected = true;
  }
}
```

However, I want to be able to search directly in the drop down menu, something like what this [plugin](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) does.

Is there anyway to integrate the two? For example, could I somehow combine the input and output's so the search is at the top of the drop down?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Are you asking whether it's possible to put a textbox directly in a select dropdown?

Comment: you need to play around with css and jquery here.. your actual html elements hides, and a new element has to be created with ul and li's..

Comment: @Kyle is that possible? If so, that could be helpful. I want to be able to type in at the top of the drop down and search for the items.

Comment: @AndréDion This absolutely works! But this is not the end result I want. I want to be able to search directly in the drop down.

Comment: No, it's not. Look at how select2 does it with a textbox and a list, you'll need to build the dom to replace the standard select.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need something like this ?

```js
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Source : https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: I don't want to use a plugin. I am trying to build this natively.